# Paperclip not uploading images, rollback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

Paperclip does not upload images. Printing the output of the object the image is attached to show that no image is uploaded.

Console:

```
irb(main):011:0> b = Article.find(9)
  Article Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Article id: 9, title: "Rails", body: "Server", created_at: "2017-07-07 15:05:41", updated_at: "2017-07-07 15:05:41", image_
file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil>
irb(main):012:0>
```

Log:

```
Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/addis/AppData/Local/Temp/4d3d12fcec1dd8d0eff643aa438c2b9120170708-9872-8pkize.jpg"
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename 2006-05-09_01.19.32.jpg (image/jpeg from Headers, ["image/jpeg"] from Extension), conte
nt type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.
Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/addis/AppData/Local/Temp/4d3d12fcec1dd8d0eff643aa438c2b9120170708-9872-knt072.jpg"
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename 2006-05-09_01.19.32.jpg (image/jpeg from Headers, ["image/jpeg"] from Extension), conte
nt type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/articles/1
Completed 302 Found in 49ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

helper method:

```
module ArticlesHelper

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body, :tag_list, :image)
  end

end
```

Model:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :comments
    has_many :taggings
    has_many :tags, through: :taggings
    has_attached_file :image
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"]

    def tag_list
    self.tags.collect do |tag|
        tag.name
    end.join(", ")
    end
    def tag_list=(tags_string)
        tag_names = tags_string.split(",").collect{|s| s.strip.downcase}.uniq
        new_or_found_tags = tag_names.collect {|name| Tag.find_or_create_by(name: name)}
        self.tags = new_or_found_tags
    end 
end
```

Running on Windows 10, using Visual Code.

Following this [guide](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i3:-tagging).

Answer (score 0):

I think if it's rollback, the problem is from your validation.
below is sample code format for validates_attachment that probably you can try

```
has_attached_file :image
validates_attachment :image, :content_type => { :content_type => ["application/octet-stream","image/jpg","image/jpeg","image/png"] }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried you solution to no avail. I did however, found a github issue which mirrors my problem: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/2241